# Decorate all services that implement the same interface by default?

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, decorator, symfony4

I have a growing number of service classes that share a common interface (let's say `BarService` and `BazService`, that implement `FooInterface`).

All of these need to be decorated with the same decorator. Reading the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/4.3/service_container/service_decoration.html), I know that I can do:

```
services:
  App\BarDecorator:
    # overrides the App\BarService service
    decorates: App\BarService
```

Since I have to use the same decorator for different services I guess I would need to do:

```
services:
 bar_service_decorator:
    class: App\BarDecorator
    # overrides the App\BarService service
    decorates: App\BarService

 baz_service_decorator:
    class: App\BarDecorator
    # overrides the App\BazService service
    decorates: App\BazService
```

Problem is: this gets repetitive, quickly. And every time a new implementation of `FooInterface` is created, another set needs to be added to the configuration.

How can I declare that I want to decorate all services that implement `FooInterface` automatically, without having to declare each one individually?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A [compiler pass](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/compiler_passes.html) allows to modify the container programmatically, to alter service definitions or add new ones.

First you'll need a way to locate all implementations of `FooInterface`. You can do this with the help of [autoconfigure](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/tags.html#autoconfiguring-tags):

```
services:
    _instanceof:
        App\FooInterface:
            tags: ['app.bar_decorated']
```

Then you'll need to create the compiler pass that collects all `FooServices` and creates a new decorated definition:

```
// src/DependencyInjection/Compiler/FooInterfaceDecoratorPass.php
namespace App\DependencyInjection\Compiler;

use App\BarDecorator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class FooInterfaceDecoratorPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        if (!$container->has(BarDecorator::class)) {
            // If the decorator isn't registered in the container you could register it here
            return;
        }            

        $taggedServices = $container->findTaggedServiceIds('app.bar_decorated');

        foreach ($taggedServices as $id => $tags) {

            // skip the decorator, we do it's not self-decorated
            if ($id === BarDecorator::class) {
                continue;
            }

            $decoratedServiceId = $this->generateAliasName($id);

            // Add the new decorated service.
            $container->register($decoratedServiceId, BarDecorator::class)
                ->setDecoratedService($id)
                ->setPublic(true)
                ->setAutowired(true);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Generate a snake_case service name from the service class name
     */
    private function generateAliasName($serviceName)
    {
        if (false !== strpos($serviceName, '\\')) {
            $parts = explode('\\', $serviceName);
            $className = end($parts);                
            $alias = strtolower(preg_replace('/[A-Z]/', '_\\0', lcfirst($className)));
        } else {
            $alias = $serviceName;
        }
        return $alias . '_decorator';            
    }
}
```

Finally, register the compiler pass in the kernel:

```
// src/Kernel.php
use App\DependencyInjection\Compiler\FooInterfaceDecoratorPass;

class Kernel extends BaseKernel
{
    // ...

    protected function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $container->addCompilerPass(new FooInterfaceDecoratorPass());
    }
}
```

Comment: The only thing I would add, it's a condition to skip the decorator, so we do not decorate the decorator with itself. I'll edit that in.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting! I think that's going to be tricky... but maybe with some hints here you might come up with a solution that fits your needs

- find all Decorators...  not sure if there's an easier way in that case but I use  tags for that. So create a `DecoratorInterface` add auto tag it...
- loop through the definitions and and modify and set the decorated service

e. g. in your `Kernel` or `AcmeAwesomeBundle` do

```
protected function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $container->registerForAutoconfiguration(DecoratorInterface::class)
        ->addTag('my.decorator.tag');

    $decoratorIds = $container->findTaggedServiceIds('my.decorator.tag');

    foreach ($decoratorIds as $decoratorId) {
        $definition = $container->getDefinition($decoratorId);

        $decoratedServiceId = $this->getDecoratedServiceId($definition);

        $definition->setDecoratedService($decoratedServiceId);
    }
}

private function getDecoratedServiceId(Definition $decoratorDefinition): string
{
    // todo
    // maybe u can use the arguments here
    // e.g. the first arg is always the decoratedService
    // might not work because the arguments are not resolved yet?
    $arg1 = $decoratorDefinition->getArgument(0);
    // or use a static function in your DecoratorInterface like
    // public static function getDecoratedServiceId():string;
    $class = $decoratorDefinition->getClass();
    $decoratedServiceId = $class::getDecoratedServiceId();

    return 'myDecoratedServiceId';
}
```

I'm pretty sure this is not complete yet but let us know how you solved it